# Feynmp / metapost - labels not working

Tags: metapost, feynmf, feynman

I am trying to draw a simple Feynman diagram with FeynMP. I use the following code to generate by *.mp file - note I use the fmfgraphs* environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\begin{document}
    \unitlength = 1mm
    \begin{fmffile}{PandS6214}
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,30)
           \fmfleft{i1,i2}
           \fmfright{o1}
           \fmf{fermion, tension = 1}{i1,d1,v1}
           \fmf{fermion, tension = 1}{v1,d2,i2}
           \fmflabel{i1}{i1}
           \fmflabel{i2}{i2}
           \fmflabel{o1}{o1}
           \fmf{photon}{v1,o1}
           \fmffreeze
          \fmf{dashes}{d1,d2}
          \fmfdot{v1}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

And when I run TexStudio I get the following .mp file

```
% PandS6213.mp -- do not edit, generated automatically by feyneg.tex
input feynmp
require_RCS_revision "1.30";
beginchar(1, 40*2.84526pt#, 30*2.84526pt#, 0);
"feynmf: 1";
LaTeX_unitlength:=2.84526pt;
subgraph (0, 0, w, h);
vinit;
pickup pencircle scaled thin;
vleft (__i1, __i2);
vright (__o1);
vconnect ("fermion, tension = 1", __i1, __d1, __v1);
vconnect ("fermion, tension = 1", __v1, __d2, __i2);
vlabel ("i1", __i1);
vlabel ("i2", __i2);
vlabel ("o1", __o1);
vconnect ("photon", __v1, __o1);
vfreeze;
vconnect ("dashes", __d1, __d2);
vdot (__v1);
vfreeze;
vdraw;
endsubgraph;
endchar;
% the end.
end.
endinput;
```

I copy and paste this code in Troy Henderson's Metapost previewer: http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/ and the diagram shows up perfectly but the labels do not!

I compiled the tex code with TexStudio for Windows ... pls let me know what I am doing wrong!

John

Comment: Do you get the labels in your document? If so, this is a problem in the online Metapost previewer.

Comment: I used TexStudio to compile the Metapost and then run GSView to view the .ps file, with Ghostview. I get the same output as with the previewer

Comment: If I do `latex+mpost+latex+dvips+ps2pdf` or `pdflatex+mpost+pdflatex` I get the labels (I'm not on Windows, though).

Comment: Hmm - interestingly on TexStudio there are two files it gives me after I run MetaPost. I get a *.1 file and a *.t1. The *.t1 file contains the labels. However, I can't seem to compile both of them together to get the labels and diagrams to show. Either way I would expect that the Previewer would display the lables as it comes direct from Metapost ....

Answer (score 6):

The MP file you get doesn't generate the labels, which are stored in the `.t1` file connected to the picture. When `feynmp` includes the image, it will also place the labels getting their positions from the data in the `.t1` file. So the Metapost previewer can't show them, because they aren't part of the generated picture and are added only on the LaTeX side.

Comment: Got it - makes sense. Is there a way I can include them in .1 file or will this outcome always be the case. As an aside I did: latex+mpost+latex+dvips+psview to get the image in TexStudio and it worked ...

Comment: @JohnB I don't think so; it's the way `feynmp` chose in order to have matching fonts in the diagrams with the text fonts.

Comment: Just another thought -- in the mp file the labels are included. See the vlabel ... code ...i.e., the labels are generated from running mpost, creating the .1 .t1 files -- in those it makes sense the labels are separate. However, in the .mp file the labels seem to be there.

Comment: I think they're used just to get the coordinates that are written in the `.t1` file. *Maybe* one can redefine `vlabel` to add the label to the Postscript output. Do you want to try? ;-)

Comment: Okay - thanks. That is WELL beyond my capability!